# What can prevent lsattr from being able to list the attributes of a file in Linux in WSL2?

Tags: linux, file-permissions

**Windows 10 -> WSL 2 Pengwin (Debian)**
([This question](https://superuser.com/questions/1656286/mv-cannot-move-permission-denied-in-wsl) relates to WSL 1)

I'm trying to modify an executable (`npm` in this case) but am getting denied all the way. At this stage I just want to at least `lattr` the file to see if it's immutable but can't figure out why not.

Modifying with **`sudo mv npm npm_from_apt`**

`mv: cannot move 'npm' to 'npm_from_apt_install': Permission denied`

Changing permissions with **`sudo chmod 744 npm`**

`chmod: changing permissions of 'npm': Permission denied`

Checking if it's immutable with **`lsattr npm`**

`lsattr: Operation not supported While reading flags on npm`

It's not a symlink either **`ls -l npm`**

`-r-xr--r-- 1 quack quack 324 Jun  1  2021 npm`

What else should I try?

Comment: Please don’t repost closed questions. Instead, have them reopened.